# TinyMCE not submitting content

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, tinymce

I am trying to implement TinyMCE in my ruby on rails app

I was getting the error content cannot be blank, so I found on another question that I needed to use javascript to save but now its just complaining about my script

I suspect im doing the script wrong because I have almost zero javascript knowledge

```
<div class="field">
   <%= f.label :content %><br>
   <%= text_area_tag :content, "", :class => "tinymce", :id => "editor" :rows => 20, :cols => 80 %>
   <%= tinymce :plugins => ["wordcount","image","autoresize","media","lists","link","save","searchreplace"] %>

   <script>
     var editor = tinymce.get("editor");
     editor.save();
   </script>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it didnt require javascript saving after all, finally found the answer deep on youtube

the text_area_tag line needed to be changed because the previous code is for a model-less implementation

To make it work for a model:

```
<%= f.text_area :content, :class => "tinymce", :id => "editor" :rows => 20, :cols => 80 %>
```

I really wish that they would include that on the tinymce-rails page